# Separate users content by year chosen

Tags: 7, views, datetime

Website has several types of users and all can post images, videos, events etc.

One user type is hard to solve for me.

This user type is summer school that is happening every year and last for few weeks.

This user as all other can post images, videos, events etc. but i would like to separate all of these by the year.
So summer school happened in 2009, 2010, 2011 etc.

For other user types i have menu in sidebar:
Bio
Photos
Videos
Etc.

For summer school i have the same menu but somehow i would like to have a year above the menu with drop down if possible ? When year is picked website should remember it so the menu gives content based on year picked.

Also when user (summer school) creates content it should be able to pick which year it happened. I can use date field here i guess, but the bio should remain the same for any year chosen.

Hope i was clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

A "user type" is a role, right?

You can create a Year field as either a Date, Taxonomy, or plain Text field.  Then you can attach it to each of the content types that these users are allowed to post.

I have not used it myself, but I think that the [Field permissions](https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module will let you restrict this field to just the desired role.  If that does not work, you could do a little theme work to add the user's role(s) as CSS classes on the `<body>` tag, then hide the Year widget with CSS.

Comment: How about that site visitor goes on user profile and picks a year there for example 2009, then when you pick a link from menu it reflects that year only.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.  Yes, you can have a profile field for the year.  Say a user has this field set.  Do you want that year attached to content created by this user?  You should be able to do that with the Rules module or a little custom code.  Do you want this user to see content tagged with his or her year?  I think you can do that with the Context module.